# Stumped by simple change of variable in integration

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

[This article](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2022/11/02/elliptic-arc-length/) contains a seemingly simple change of variable

$$
\int_0^T \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2(t) + b^2 \cos^2(t)}  \; \mathrm dt = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2} - T}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2(u) + b^2 \sin^2(u)} \; \mathrm du
$$

I just about understand that $\frac{\pi}{2} - T$ has been added to the limits of the integration, however I struggle to explain why this is valid nor am I able to explain the change in the integrand.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(\frac\pi2-x)=\sin(x)$ and $\sin(\frac\pi2-x)=\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider integration as the signed area under a curve it is easy to understand

we have $f(x)=\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}$

No we want the area between 0 and T(ill take T=$\pi$,a=1,b=2 for convenience)

Now if we plot from 0 to $\pi$ we get

[image: graph1]

Now if we look at the plot of $f(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ from $\frac{\pi}{2}-T=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

[image]

We see that they look identical and have the same area

This is supported by rigorous arguments in calculus books

Comment: Thanks. I get this part. The way I'm thinking about it is that if we decide to shift the function, by $\frac{\pi}{2} - T$, such that $T$ becomes $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $0$ becomes $\frac{\pi}{2} - T$. This explains the limits.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand how $sin(t)$ becomes $cos(u)$. Using the trig formulae $sin(t) = sin \left(u - (\frac{\pi}{2} - T) \right) = sin(u)$.

Comment: We dont shift the function exactly shifting you add when you subtract is more like flipping and shifting we have two integration variables t and $u=(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)$ T is not including in the substitution its $sin^2(t)=sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-u)=cos^2(u)$